# Read the values of variables from a TXT file in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have the following program in Proccessing and I try to find a way to read the values ​​of variables from a TXT file.

```
static final int ribbon_length = 255, H = 200; 

void setup() {
  size(ribbon_length, H); //Διαστάσεις παλέτας
}

void draw() {
  float p = 1;
  int up_y = 10;
  int widthh = 1;
  int height = 180;
  float a = pow (ribbon_length, 1-p);
  float colour = 0;
  for (int step = 0; step <= 255; step++) { 
      colour = a * pow (step, p);
      fill(colour,0,0); 
      rect(widthh*step, up_y, widthh, height);
      noStroke();
   }
}
```

The values tha I want to read from the txt is

```
  float p = 1; 
  int up_y = 10; 
  int widthh = 1;
  int height = 180;
```

I found [BufferedReader](http://www.processing.org/reference/BufferedReader.html) command but I'm not sure if it is thaτ I want. I try ρθν an example..but it didn't work...

```
BufferedReader reader;
String line;
static final int ribbon_length = 255, H = 200;

void setup() {
  size(ribbon_length, H);
  reader = createReader("positions.txt");  
}
.
.
.
.
```

Any ideas????

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your answers. 
I try some changes after your commends. But It didn't show any color.

```
static final int ribbon_length = 255, H = 200; 

void setup() {
  size(ribbon_length, H);
}

void draw() {
  String[] lines = loadStrings("input.txt");
  float p = float(split(lines[0], "=")[1]);
  int up_y = int(split(lines[1], "=")[1]);
  int wide = int(split(lines[2], "=")[1]);
  int high = int(split(lines[3], "=")[1]);
  float a = pow (ribbon_length, 1-p);
  float colour = 0;
  for (int step = 0; step <= 255; step++) { 
      colour = a * pow (step, p);
      fill(colour,0,0); 
      rect(wide*step, up_y, wide, high);
      noStroke();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file `positions.txt` exists? Are you sure the file `positions.txt` is in the same directory where the sketch `.pde` file is? Also `it didn't work...`...what exactly happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a plain txt where each of the lines is a variable, so you can use the BufferedReader like this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName.txt"));
```

Then you read each line with `br.readLine()` and then you finally assign the read line to the variable, transforming it to the necessary type. For example, if your line is an int you would have to do

`int myInt = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())`

You can also have a properties file, in which every line has the format "key = value". You can try this webpage to load that properties file: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ (check part 2: Loading a properties file)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added a processing-specific answer, as yours uses pure java only.

Answer (score 1):

First: it's a bad idea to name variables `width` and `height` because these are special variables built into Processing. You should use something different, like `wide` and `high`, perhaps.

The simplest way to do it is to have a bare text file like this:

```
1
10
1
180
```

exactly as I have written it. You can then use the built-in functions of Processing to read in these values. These are easier alternatives to what xp500's answer provides, which is the correct answer for pure java.

```java
void setup(){
  ....
  String[] lines = loadStrings("positions.txt");
  float p = float(lines[0]);
  int up_y = int(lines[1]);
  int wide = int(lines[2]);
  int high = int(lines[3]);
  ....
}
```

This will work, but is not very maintainable because there are lots of hard-coded values. What if there's an extra empty line at the top of the text file? The first line (`lines[0]`) won't have `p`'s value, and the second line (`lines[1]`) will have `p`'s values instead of `up_y`'s! This is just something to keep in mind. If you end up having other things in your text file (such as variable names), you could use [split()](http://processing.org/reference/split_.html) to get the number out of the string. Example:

text file:

```
p=1
up_y=10
```

processing code:

```java
String[] lines = loadStrings("input.txt")
float p = float(split(lines[0], "=")[1]); // split on the "=" and take the second element
int up_y = int(split(lines[1], "=")[1]);
```

If you choose this approach, you might even check for the variable name in the line before assigning it, just in case the file is jumbled. Something like `if(!lines[0].contains("p")) print("error!");`