# Read values from a text in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I tried to convert the following program in Processing to read the variables from a txt file with help of [Kevinsa5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815517/read-the-values-of-variables-from-a-txt-file-in-processing), but I don't know why didn't work. What did I do wrong? Τhe program runs without displaying any errors just the canvas that opens does not show any color as should.

```
static final int ribbon_length = 255, H = 200;

void setup() {
  size(ribbon_length, H);
}

void draw() {
  String[] lines = loadStrings("input.txt");
  float p = float(split(lines[0], "=")[1]);
  int up_y = int(split(lines[1], "=")[1]);
  int wide = int(split(lines[2], "=")[1]);
  int high = int(split(lines[3], "=")[1]);
  float a = pow (ribbon_length, 1-p);
  float colour = 0;
  for (int step = 0; step <= 255; step++) {
      colour = a * pow (step, p);
      fill(colour,0,0);
      rect(wide*step, up_y, wide, high);
      noStroke();
   }
}
```

Comment: Whats the content of **input.txt** ? and post **loadStrings** as well.

Comment: something like that.
  
  float p = 5;
  int up_y = 10;
  int wide = 5;
  int high = 10;

Comment: @Sanjeev `loadStrings` is built into Processing, which is a java language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the semicolons is a good idea, as it simplifies what your code has to do. However, splitting the string along the `=` gives you `"float p "` and `" 5"` -- notice the space before the 5! The space before the number in the string makes it unparseable:

```
println("with a space: \t" + int(" 5"));
println("without a space: \t" + int("5"));
```

gives this output:

```
with a space:       0
without a space:    5
```

Now, to your code. You definitely don't need to be reading the text file 60 times per second, so move that from `draw()` to `setup()`. Since you want to remove that space before the value for each one, you could either edit your text file like you did with the semicolon, or just change how you're splitting it. Instead of splitting on `"="`, split on `" = "`. This represents the above changes:

```
static final int ribbon_length = 255, H = 200;
float p;
int up_y, wide, high;

void setup() {
  size(ribbon_length, H);
  String[] lines = loadStrings("input.txt");
  p = float(split(lines[0], " = ")[1]);
  println(p);
  up_y = int(split(lines[1], " = ")[1]);
  println(up_y);
  wide = int(split(lines[2], " = ")[1]);
  println(wide);
  high = int(split(lines[3], " = ")[1]);
  println(high);
}

void draw() {
  float a = pow (ribbon_length, 1-p);
  float colour = 0;
  for (int step = 0; step <= 255; step++) {
      colour = a * pow (step, p);
      fill(colour,0,0);
      rect(wide*step, up_y, wide, high);
      noStroke();
   }
}
```

And this is the input:

```
float p = 5
int up_y = 10
int wide = 5
int high = 10
```

When you run into behavior that you don't expect, a first effort for debugging is usually using `println()` to look at the values of variables. In your code, it would have printed `0` for most of them, showing that somehow the numbers in your text file weren't making it into the variables (either you're reading them wrong or you're parsing them wrong). Then, printing something like `println(split(lines[0], "=")[1])` would, if you have a careful eye, reveal the extra space. Then you could have your answer in a couple minutes instead of having to wait 16+ hours for someone to answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

If your input is as you specified in your reply to Sanjeevs comment (e.g float p=5; int up_y = 10; etc), then you are having problems because you are not just loading a number into the variable, you are also loading the semi-colon as well.

For example, take the first line of your text file, 'float p = 5;'. When you split this string at the '=', the two parts are going to be 'float' and '5;'. The variable type float can not deal with semi colons.

To solve this problem, I recommend editing 'intput.txt' and removing the semi-colons at the end of each line. You should then be loading just the number into your variable.

Comment: I delete it but, nothing.